# Spring security: simultaneous login to different OIDC

Tags: spring-security, openid-connect

I have following scenario:

APP_1: OIDC_PROVIDER_1

APP_2: OIDC_PROVIDER_1, OIDC_PROVIDER_2

If a user log in to APP_2 with OIDC_PROVIDER_2 I want that he is still able to login to OIDC_PROVIDER_1 in order to have oauth access to APP_1.

Can I do it with spring security?

---

Here a code snippet of my SecurityConfig class for APP_2.

It works if I choose to connect with OIDC_PROVIDER_1 or OIDC_PROVIDER_2, but how to configure it correctly to work with both? How to check if we are already connected to OIDC_PROVIDER_1?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.oauth2Login().successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler()).and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler(myLogoutSuccessHandler());
    }

  @Bean
  MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler(){
    return new MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
  }

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(@Nullable ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository b) {
        if(clientRegistrationRepository==null)return null;

        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrationRepository,b);
        oauth2Client.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
        oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("myClientId");
        return WebClient.builder()
            .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
            .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                    .codecs(configurer->configurer
                            .defaultCodecs()
                            .maxInMemorySize(32*1024*1024))
                    .build())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistration myClientRegistration(){
        ClientRegistration.Builder builder=ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("myClientId")
            .clientName("myClientName")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
            .clientId("clientId")
            .clientSecret("clientPwd")
            .authorizationUri("userAuthorizationUri")
            .userInfoUri("userTokenInfo")
            .jwkSetUri("jwksUri")
            .tokenUri("tokenUri")
            .scope("scope")
            .redirectUriTemplate("{baseUrl}/{action}/oauth2/code/{registrationId}");

        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository myClientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(myClientRegistration());
    }

}

public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

  @Autowired(required = false)
  private WebClient webClient;

  public OpenIdConnectAuthenticationSuccessHandler(){
  }

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
  //do my stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're on the right track with your Spring Security configuration. To achieve the goal of allowing users to log in with both **OIDC_PROVIDER_1** and **OIDC_PROVIDER_2** in **APP_2**, and then access APP_1 while maintaining the existing connection to **OIDC_PROVIDER_1**, you can consider the following steps:

Configure Multiple Client Registrations:
Define client registrations for both **OIDC_PROVIDER_1** and **OIDC_PROVIDER_2** in the **ClientRegistrationRepository**. This allows you to handle authentication with both providers.

Conditional Redirect URI:
Update the **redirectUriTemplate** in the client registration to include a placeholder for the provider, so you can dynamically determine the provider when generating the redirect URI. This is important for keeping track of which provider the user is authenticated with.

Handle Provider Selection:
In your authentication success handler (MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler), determine the provider the user was authenticated with by checking the URL parameters, and then store this information. You can use a session attribute or a custom token to identify the provider.

Initiate Authentication with Different Provider:
When the user accesses APP_1, you can provide a link or button that triggers authentication with the other provider (OIDC_PROVIDER_1). Use the stored provider information from the previous step to generate the correct redirect URI.

Here's a simplified version of how you might adapt your existing code to achieve this:

```
// Inside your ClientRegistrationRepository bean definition
@Bean
public ClientRegistrationRepository myClientRegistrationRepository() {
    ClientRegistration oidcProvider1Registration = myClientRegistration("oidcProvider1");
    ClientRegistration oidcProvider2Registration = myClientRegistration("oidcProvider2");
    
    return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(oidcProvider1Registration, oidcProvider2Registration);
}

// Inside your MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Determine the provider based on request parameters or session attributes
    String provider = determineProvider(request);

    // Store the provider information in the session or as a custom token

    // Perform necessary actions based on the provider (e.g., redirect to APP_1)
    if ("oidcProvider1".equals(provider)) {
        response.sendRedirect("URL_TO_OIDC_PROVIDER_1_LOGIN");
    } else if ("oidcProvider2".equals(provider)) {
        // Perform your existing actions for OIDC_PROVIDER_2 login
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not enough. If a build  a second WebClient an try to connect myslef to PROVIDER_1 I get "not authorized". I probably have to trigger the oidc authentification process myself (at the end I need a token to connect to the external app APP_1)